# Jquery find if date is between date range

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So I am trying to find if a certain date is between two other dates and then display the correct div text. I have it working to a point, but it doesn't seem to work checking multiple divs. Heres what I have below, basically it uses the 'date-selected' div and runs through each 'date' div to find the date match.

It seems to work if the date is 02/01/2019, but if I set the date to 02/01/2020 it will not find the correct div, which should be 02/01/2020-01/01/2021. Does anyone know what the problem is?

```js
// on click
$(".check").click(function() {
  // foreach date div
  $(".date").each(function() {
    var firstdate = $(this).text().split('-')[0];
    var lastdate = $(this).text().split('-')[1];
    var fDate, lDate, cDate;
    fDate = new Date(firstdate); // firstdate
    lDate = new Date();
    lDate.setDate(lDate.getDate(lastdate)); // lastdate
    cDate = new Date($('.date-selected').text()); // date to check if between

    if (Date.parse(cDate) <= Date.parse(lDate) && Date.parse(cDate) >= Date.parse(fDate)) {
      // output matched date
      $('.correct-date').text('Date between: ' + $(this).text());
      return true;
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="date-selected">02/01/2020</div>
<div class="date">01/01/2019-01/01/2020</div>
<div class="date">02/01/2020-01/01/2021</div>
<div class="correct-date"></div>
<button class="check">check</button>
```

Comment: You don't need to `Data.parse(new Date())` it's already a date.

Comment: I guess it's working fine

Comment: @AbhishekPandey change the date to 02/01/2020,  i just edited the code above, it should find 02/01/2020-01/01/2021, becuase 02/01/2020 is in between  02/01/2020 and 01/01/2021

Comment: `02/01/2019 > 01/01/2019 && 02/01/2019 < 01/01/2020` is true and `02/01/2019 > 02/01/2020 && 02/01/2019 < 01/01/2021` is false

Comment: Add some *basic* debugging: `console.log(fDate, lDate, cDate, cDate <= lDate, cDate >= fDate)` - you'll see ldate is always the same.  Change how you set lDate to the same as fDate.

Answer (score 0):

not need to `new Date`,
only use `Date.parse`:

```js
$(".check").click(function() {
  // foreach date div
  $(".date").each(function() {

    if (
        dateCheck(
          $(this).text().split('-')[0], 
          $(this).text().split('-')[1], 
          $('.date-selected').text()
        )
    ) {
      // output matched date
      $('.correct-date').text('Date between: ' + $(this).text());
      return true;
    }
  });
});

function dateCheck(from,to,check) {

    var fDate,lDate,cDate;
    fDate = Date.parse(from);
    lDate = Date.parse(to);
    cDate = Date.parse(check);

    if((cDate <= lDate && cDate >= fDate)) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="date-selected">02/01/2020</div>
<div class="date">01/01/2019-01/01/2020</div>
<div class="date">02/01/2020-01/01/2021</div>
<div class="correct-date"></div>
<button class="check">check</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [getTime()](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/compare-two-dates-using-javascript/) for compare date:

```js
// on click
$(".check").click(function() {
  // foreach date div
  $(".date").each(function() {
    var firstdate = $(this).text().split('-')[0];
    var lastdate = $(this).text().split('-')[1];
    var fDate, lDate, cDate;
    fDate = new Date(firstdate); // firstdate
    lDate = new Date(lastdate);
    //lDate.setDate(lDate.getDate(lastdate)); // lastdate
    cDate = new Date($('.date-selected').text()); // date to check if between

    if (cDate.getTime() <= lDate.getTime() && cDate.getTime() >= fDate.getTime()) {
      // output matched date
      $('.correct-date').text('Date between: ' + $(this).text());
      return true;
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="date-selected">02/01/2020</div>
<div class="date">01/01/2019-01/01/2020</div>
<div class="date">02/01/2020-01/01/2021</div>
<div class="correct-date"></div>
<button class="check">check</button>
```